# How to replace a Column simultaneously with LOAD INFILE in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have table with a DECIMAL column  with values, for example: 128.98, 283.98, 21.20.

I want to import some CSV Files to this table. However, in the columns of these files, I have values like 235,69, 23,23, with comma instead of points.

I know I can REPLACE that column, but is there some way of doing that before LOAD INFILE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you can simultaneously replace that column and load the data. Looks like you will have to do multiple steps to get the results you want.

Load the data first into a raw table using the `LOAD INFILE` command.  This table can be identical to the main table. You can use the `Create Table like` command to create the table.

Process the data (i.e. change the comma to a . where applicable) in the raw table.

select the data from the raw table and insert into main table either with row by row processing or bulk insert.

This can all be done in a stored procedure (SP) or by a 3rd party script written in python, php, etc...

If you want to know more about SP's in Mysql, [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) is a useful link.